# Remove duplicate notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications on Flutter.
Some notifications of my chat application are repeated, for example, when 3 messages are sent in a chat, 3 notifications are sent.

I want the previous notifications to be deleted and only the last notification to be displayed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send it with a data message, not a notification

```
{
   "to":"_some_fcm_token_",
   "type": "new_message",
   "data": {
     "model":{"id":"same_user_notification_id"},
     "body": "subtitle",
     "title": "title",
     "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
   },
   "priority": "normal"
}
```

this is different between Message types :

1. Notification message
2. Data message

[About FCM messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)